# XAML works all right, but screen becomes all white at runtim in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

everyone, like title says, I have 7 projects in one solution, one project works correctly, but the others don't.
I'm using VS2019 Community, .NetCore 3.0 in WPF, my screen resolution is 1920*1080, DPI Scaling is 100%.Like I said, one project works fine, but others don't, I really can't figure out why.
[image: Capture in XAML]
Capture in XAML

[image: Capture at runtime]
Capture at runtime

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="FaceRecognition1.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FaceRecognition1"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Height="1080" Width="1920" WindowStyle="None"  WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" ResizeMode="NoResize">
<Grid Width="1920" Height="1080">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="883"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="156"></ColumnDefinition>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="881"></ColumnDefinition>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="406"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="156"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="518"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Image Source="Assets/bg-人脸识别-遮罩层.png" Width="1920" Height="1080" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3"></Image>
    <Image Source="Assets/人脸扫描成功图标-打勾.png" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1"></Image>
    <TextBlock Text="扫描成功" FontFamily="FangSong" FontSize="40" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0,241,0,0"></TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="人脸注册成功，请录入指纹"  FontFamily="FangSong" FontSize="28" FontWeight="Bold" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.Row="2" Foreground="White" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Opacity="0.6" Margin="0,299,0,0"></TextBlock>
</Grid>
```

After adding " AllowsTransparency="True" Background="Transparent" " in Window component, I have following result at runtime:
[image]

That means, I think, is image controller don't work

And structure tree is below:
[image: Structure tree of project]

Build action of Image:
[image]

Is there anything I wrongly did? Thank you.

Comment: You have a transparent window and image, which covers the entire window `Width="1920" Height="1080" Grid.ColumnSpan="3" Grid.RowSpan="3"`

Comment: Thanks for noticing that, But I deleted Allowtransparency = "True", screen is still all white at run time

Comment: Could you try changing the file names of the images to english characters only? I suspect it could be causing an issue. Also try to set `Background="Red"` to the root `Grid`, to see if at least that appears.

Comment: Hi, Martin, I will try that, but I don't think Non-English characters is the reason. Because one of seven project works correctly.

Comment: Are your Assets being copied to the output folder correctly? What is their Build Action?

Comment: Check your file paths. Also always start relative paths with a slash "_/_": `"/Assets/bg-人脸识别-遮罩层.png"`. If the images are located in a different assembly use [pack uri](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/app-development/pack-uris-in-wpf#using-pack-uris-in-markup) notation (this will always work): `"pack://application:,,,/ASSEMBLY NAME HERE;component/Assets/bg-人脸识别-遮罩层.png"`:

Comment: Hi, BionicCode, I've tried add a slash, but result is the very same.

Comment: Also make sure the Build Action of the images is set to _Resource_. You can edit it by right clicking on the corresponding image file in the Solution Explorer and select _Properties_. Now the _Properties_  pane will show. Set the field _Build Action_ to _Resource_.

Comment: Is possible that one solution corresponds to only one project? That's the reason why One among seven project in the solution works ?

Comment: Solution is the top level or root of the application. It holds one or more projects and global build definition for the projects. Which project is the only one working and why or what is not working with the other projects?

Comment: Hi, BionicCode, you are right, Build Action wasn't in Resource, But it did not change after I set it to Resource.

Comment: the project named MainPage1 works, the others dont work, I compared the worked project one word by one word with others, but It's all same, I alse started a new solution to test other non-working project, but the result is always same.

Comment: The `Window` from your example is located in the `FaceRecognition2` assemly right? How do you show it? Also make sure there is no typo in the file path and use the Pack Uri notation: `"pack://application:,,,/FaceRecognition2;component/Assets/bg-人脸识别-遮罩层.png"`.

Comment: Have you tried GAC for including  the Projects..

Comment: Hi, BionicCode, what do u mean assembly right? I'm sure there is no typo in the file path, I use resharper 2019.1.1 to help me.

Comment: Hi, AJAY, thanks for your advise, I will try GAC

Comment: I forgot the comma before the _"right"_, sorry. It was supposed to be: _"The Window from your example is located in the FaceRecognition2 assembly, right? How do you show it?"_

Comment: Also, your `Grid` is too small and can't show the content. Set its `Width` and `Height` ( `RowDefintion.Height` too) to auto and wrap it into a `ScrollViewer` instead where you set your `Height` and `Width`on. Or make the image's dimension smaller to fit into the row/column.

Comment: What your Problem

Comment: Hello, everyone, Problem solved, I just set Image Path as absolute path. If you're new to WPF just remember it, it could save you a day!!!!! Thanks also to people who tried to help me.